# C++ splitting a string gives a weird output

Tags: c++, string, vector, split

I am trying to `split` a `string` and it works. It's just when I print it to `console` I get a weird `output` like this - ╨╕[╝. Maybe someone could give a hint of what I am doing wrong? Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>


using namespace std;

vector<string> &split(const string &s, char delim, vector<string> &elems);

vector<string> split(const string &s, char delim);

int main() {

    vector<string> x = split("E:\\TEST\\filename.txt", '\\');

    int pos = x.size() - 1;
    printf("filename is %s\n", &x.at(pos));

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}

vector<string> &split(const string &s, char delim, vector<string> &elems) {
    stringstream ss(s);
    string item;
    while (getline(ss, item, delim)) {
        elems.push_back(item);
    }
    return elems;
}


vector<string> split(const string &s, char delim) {
    vector<string> elems;
    split(s, delim, elems);
    return elems;
}
```

Comment: `vector<string> &split(const string &s, char delim, vector<string> &elems) { /* ... */ return elems; }` - just wondering - why is there a return value if you don't use it?

Comment: Why not debug it to see what is exactly happening? and why you think you needed to `return` stuff? You are passing by reference, so no need to return it again. Just `void` it

Comment: @underscore_d It does not return a reference to a local variable. `elems` in `return elems` is a non-const reference passed in as a parameter.

Comment: @JamesAdkison Thanks, I realised that later

Comment: `printf("filename is %s\n", &x.at(pos));` - _ugh!_ you're passing `printf` an `std::string`, not the null-terminated C string [ `.c_str()` ] that it expects. (This is basically UB but in practical terms will end up trying to print member data such as the pointer to buffer and the size.)

Comment: @BaummitAugen I know the feeling :D fwiw I'll delete my comments to tidy this up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `printf("filename is %s\n", x.back().c_str());` to print the string.

Your problem is that you are sending the address of the string object to printf but printf expects a null-terminated char array. The member function c_str gives you just that!

Comment: This would be more like an answer if you explained why there is a problem and why this solves it.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the wrong parameter to `printf("%s")`. `%s` expects a C string (i.e. a char *), but you are passing it the address of a C++ `std::string`. This is undefined behaviour.

What you need to do is make sure you get the C-string representation of the `std::string` returned by `std::vector<std::string>::at(int)` by invoking its `c_str()` method:

`printf("filename is %s\n", x.at(pos).c_str());`